# coming out of standby, no internet for 5 minutes

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, connection

I am having this incredibly frustrating bug with my Windows 8.1 laptop when coming out of standby. I get no internet connectivity at all for at least 5 minutes. During that time, my network icon in the taskbar has a yellow icon over it.

I tried the following commands to make it works

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Nothing seems to make it work except waiting the whole 5 minutes or so.

My system special configuration has:

```
Agnitum Outpost Firewall
NOD ESET 32 Antivirus
```

I don't think it has anything to do because I tried disabling it when it didn't work but it doesn't solve the problem. The only other tweak to my system is I have some extra lines in my HOSTS file to block some common advertising domains.

How can I debug this problem?

Comment: If your applying a huge hosts blocking file, on windows 7 disabling the "Dns Client" service (which is dns caching) could be "faster". I do not know how that might be different in win 8.  At the least you could test how that works on your system, and via the speed of aquiring DNS off the web (no longer cached).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigated a little more and I found that in my Network Connections > Local Area Connection > IPV4 > Properties
I had a value hardcoded in the DNS, I set it back to "Automatic" and issue seems to have gone away for now...

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your WiFi and BIOS driver?

I had similar problems with WiFi on other notebooks before - in most cases a BIOS update did the trick.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I looked at properties for IPv4 and I saw this hard coded DNS number... I removed it now things seem ok

Comment: Good to hear you found the problem. Maybe put your solution in an own answer and mark your question as complete :) Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 1):

More than likely it is a feature in your power options

> Navigate to the **control panel** and open the **Device Manager**. Open the
>   **Network adapters** section, right-click your wifi adapter and choose
>   **Properties**. Navigate to the **Power Management** tab, uncheck **allow the
>   computer to turn off this device** and set it to **allow this device to
>   wake the computer** and then save the changes you made.

Reference:
[Wifi turns off during sleep mode - tomshardware](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/48676-63-wifi-turns-sleep-mode)